# How do I get the names of users when retrieving the list of tasks?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

In a SharePoint Hosted App, with the following code, I can retrieve the list of tasks, every task containing, among others, the identifiers `AssignedToId` (an array of integers):

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists' +
        '/getByTitle('MyTasks')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Instead of the identifier of the users, I want to show the titles of the persons. I can retrieve the title through `GetUserById(1)` or `GetUsers`, but this leads to an additional AJAX call I want to avoid.

Is there a way to retrieve this information in a single call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('MyTasks')/Items?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=AssignedTo/FirstName,AssignedTo/LastName
```

(Tested on 365)

Note that you need to `$select` all the fields you need when using `$expand` like this.

Comment: Nice! I thought `$expand` can be applied to values only, not arrays of values.